# LARAVEL DOMPDF Wrapper for Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-routing, dompdf

I performed the following steps and have an error

step 1

Insert en composer.json

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*"
```

step 2
install

```
php composer update
```

step 3

add  config/app.php

'providers' => [....

```
 Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

'aliases' => [....

```
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

step 4

routes.php

```
Route::resource('pdf', 'PdfController');
```

step 5 create controller from php artisan make:controller PhpController

insert code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class PdfController extends Controller
{
public function Index() {

$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();

}}
```

step 5 ERROR

call url localhost/public/pdf

```
FatalThrowableError in PdfController.php line 16:
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App' not found
```

line 22 ....

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
```

Thank you! for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to **use** the App Facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to prefix the `App` namespace with `\`. The correct way to call that function would be as follows:

```
$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
```